# Javascript not entering function with .php file reference

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

long time answer-seeker, first time question-asker.

I am configuring a small snippet of js which is referenced in the page footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.site.com/wp-content/themes/spacious/js/jsfile.js?ver=1.0.5'></script>
```

Here is the html for the inputs:

```
<div>
    <form id="search" action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="str" name="str" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="search" />
    </form>
    <div id="search_results"></div>
</div>
```

js script file as follows:

```
(function func() {
    $("#search").bind('submit', function () {
        var value = $('#str').val();

        $.post('db_query.php', {
            value: value
        }, function (data) {
            $("#search_results").html(data);
        }); 

        return false;
    });
});
```

php file as follows:

```
<?php
    try {
        $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=xxxx','user','pass');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PDO connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);
    }

    $sql=$db->prepare("SELECT top 20 Timestamp,Information,Location FROM Table WHERE JobReference = :val");
    $sql->execute(array(':val'=>$_REQUEST['value']));

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<th>Date Time</th><th>Information</th><th>Location</th>';

    while ($row=$sql->fetch())
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$row[Timestamp]</td><td>$row[Information]</td><td>$row[Location]</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

When I try to use Chrome to debug, it stops on the first '(' and then jumps to the end of the function.  At first I thought it was because of the .php file reference, but it seems like it is not even hitting it?

I don't know where to go with this...

Many thanks, Cameron.

Comment: You don't need that `(` at the beginning. It can just be `function func(){`. You can also remove the extra `)` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Nano answer, you can fix like this:

```
(function($) { //pass $ as jQuery in this scope
$("#search").bind('submit', function () {
    var value = $('#str').val();
    $.post('db_query.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {
        $("#search_results").html(data);
    }); return false;
  });
})(jQuery); //$ is jQuery
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gave the same error as without jQuery within the parentheses, as per Nano's above. -- EDIT -- I missed the $ in the initial parentheses - now I have the PHP file not being found..

Comment: There might be something odd.

Answer (score 1):

You are just declaring a JavaScript Function called `func`. But you also have to call that function in order to make your code work.

Add another bracket to the end of your function like this:

```
(function func() {
$("#search").bind('submit', function () {
    var value = $('#str').val();
    $.post('db_query.php', {
        value: value
    }, function (data) {
        $("#search_results").html(data);
    }); return false;
  });
})();
```

Comment: Might as well remove `func` as well. To create a closure you put your code inside `(function(){ /*in here*/ })()`.

Comment: Wow you're fast - this moved the cursor into the function, then sprouted another error on line 2: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: Yes, he could remove the Function name as well. But it's not neccessary to make the code work. Maybe he need's the function name later.

Comment: @CameronB Have you included jQuery into you HTML?

Comment: Yep: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.site.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>

Comment: Before the other script-tag?

Comment: Yes, well before; Bhojendra below has corrected this issue using $ in the initial parentheses and jQuery in the last parentheses.  now the function is working but the php file is not found -- looks like I need to find the correct path to the file..

Comment: POST http://test.site.com/where-to-find-us/db_query.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED